# Hierarchical numbering in SQL result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that does a few full joins on some generally hierarchical data.  Categories have Groups, and Groups have Items, though Groups and Items may be unattached to Categories and Groups, respectively.  The results I'd like would look like this:

```
I. NULL
  A. NULL
    1. Item Orphan <-- no category or group
  B. Group Red <-- no category
    1. Item Apple
    2. Item Banana
II. Category Bacon
  A. Group Blue
  B. Group Taupe
    1. Item Kiwi
    2. Item Watermelon
III. Category Atari
  A. Group Silver
IV. Category Maui
...
```

Note: I added the periods after the numbering to make the example more readable, but the output needn't have them.

Right now the results look like this:

```
Category Group  Item
NULL     NULL   Orphan
NULL     Red    Apple
NULL     Red    Banana
Bacon    Blue   NULL
Bacon    Taupe  Kiwi
Bacon    Taupe  Watermelon
Atari    Silver NULL
Maui     NULL   NULL
```

And what I need is:

```
Co  Category Go Group  Io Item
I   NULL     A  NULL   1  Orphan
I   NULL     B  Red    1  Apple
I   NULL     B  Red    2  Banana
II  Bacon    A  Blue   1  NULL
II  Bacon    B  Taupe  1  Kiwi
II  Bacon    B  Taupe  2  Watermelon
III Atari    A  Silver 1  NULL
IV  Maui     A  NULL   1  NULL
```

Although, the `A` on the last row and the `1`s in the `Io` column on rows with `NULL` Items could also be `NULL`s.  The `I` and the `A` on the Orphan Item row are important, though.

**edit**: This is simplified from the actual code for readability.  In my case Items may have 0 or more Sub-items, so there may be multiple rows for each Item where the values for `Co`, `Go`, and `Io` would simply be duplicated.  Sub-items aren't numbered though, so there's no ordinal column for them.  So an example of some full rows would look like this:

```
Co  Category Go Group  Io Item       Supplier  Supplier_phone
I   NULL     B  Red    2  Banana     NULL      NULL
II  Bacon    B  Taupe  1  Kiwi       Steve     555-1234
II  Bacon    B  Taupe  1  Kiwi       Sally     555-4242
II  Bacon    B  Taupe  2  Watermelon NULL      NULL
```

My problem is twofold:

- how do I do the different numbering for each level of the hierarchy and have it increment whenever that level changes?
- how do I translate those numbers into a different ordinal space (e.g. translate 1,2,3 into a,b,c or I,II,III) and do so on a per-level basis?

This is in MS SQL Server 2012.  I only have access to SQL, so T-SQL code is out.

For reference, the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses together in my query are about 20 lines of code that I'd like to keep DRY.  I've used CTEs before, but I'm not sure if that would be useful in this case or not.

I'm familiar with using `row_number over (order by...`, but I don't see how I could use it in this case.

Comment: There will never be any levels lower than `items` in the hierarchy?

Comment: I simplified it from my real use case, but yes, there will be.  I'll update the question to reflect that.  Good call, as this feels like something where that could make a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the group numbers, I believe you want `DENSE_RANK`.  It is used the same way as `ROW_NUMBER`, except for groups.

Without seeing your real code, it will be something like:

```
SELECT    DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY Category) as Co,
          Category,
          DENSE_RANK() over (PARTITION BY Category, ORDER BY [Group]) as Go,
          Group,
          --etc
```

That said, I have no idea how you will convert numerics to numerals/letters without functions.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't really grasped the different keywords in the `ROW_NUMBER` code I'd used by copy/paste/modify before.  Now I finally understand what the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` do there as well as in `DENSE_RANK`.  As for the conversion, I *think* I can manage that in the code that consumes the query results, though if I had to I could probably get some horrible translation going for a limited range using `CASE` statements if I had to :O Thanks again.

Comment: @jinglesthula Glad it helped, and those 'aha' moments are the best.  I very much hope the translations are manageable in the code, as I would not wish those case statements on anyone. :D  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to do the translation for roman numerals in the code (thankfully!). In case it saves anyone a bit of googling, the roman numeral algorithm I wrote was a port of this one http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NumberToRoman.aspx